# SQL query templating in Python to emulate Periscope Data

Tags: python, sql, templating

Does anyone know of a tool or library for SQL-specific templating, preferably in Python?

I am looking for similar capabilities in Periscope Data's SQL dialect, for example [automatic joins](https://doc.periscopedata.com/article/automatic-joins) and SQL snippets.

I can approximate this myself in various templating languages like Jinja, but would be great if something out there is designed with SQL-specific use cases in mind.

Also note that this is for analytics use cases where ORM doesn't make sense, and writing SQL would be more convenient.  I am looking for analyst-friendly SQL with shortcuts like `select * from [table1+table2]` etc.

Comment: Well, besides many other things, an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) also knows how to automatically join tables if you ask it to relate particular objects. If you're not familiar with it, you should definitely have a look at [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org). But its capabilities go way beyond just SQL templating.

Comment: edited to indicate that I'm looking at analytics use cases specifically, where ORM isn't as good as a fit.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on [softwarerecs.SE] (or _maybe_ [dba.SE]) than [SO].

Comment: Asked the question on Software Recommendations and made a close vote

Answer (score 0):

I never used Periscope Data, but it looks like you might be looking for something like SQLAlchemy. SQLAlchemy can be used with or without an SQLAlchemy ORM, for example with the SQLAlchemy Expression Language (from [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html)):

```
stmt = select([users.c.name, addresses.c.email_address]).\
    select_from(users.join(addresses)).\
    limit(1).offset(1)
result = conn.execute(stmt).fetchall()
```

Which is equivalent to running the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT users.name, addresses.email_address
FROM users JOIN addresses ON users.id = addresses.user_id
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
# data for parameterized query: (1, 1)
```

or when using the ORM (from [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html)):

```
result = session.query(User).join(Address).\
    filter(Address.email_address=='jack@google.com').\
    all()
```

which is equivalent to this SQL query:

```
SELECT users.id AS users_id,
        users.name AS users_name,
        users.fullname AS users_fullname,
        users.password AS users_password
FROM users JOIN addresses ON users.id = addresses.user_id
WHERE addresses.email_address = ?
# data for parameterized query: ('jack@google.com',)
```

SQLAlchemy can guess the automatic join criteria based on the configured foreign key relationships on the table definition and/or model.

Normally, SQLAlchemy don't introspect the relationships on pre-existing table, instead it uses explicitly defined relationships in SQLAlchemy table definition and/or model, but you can use [autoload](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html) or [automap](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html) to introspect table definitions models from existing database if you really want to do that.

Comment: except that I'm looking for analyst-friendly SQL syntax with shortcuts, rather than a Python DSL for building queries.